# Assigning a struct using similar struct of pointers in Go

Tags: pointers, go, struct, go-gorm

I have two structures that are similar and I want to assign one to the other.
The first one "Equipment" is the structure used to match the database. The second one "JsonEquipment" is the helper structure to parse JSON data.

Here is the example:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID         uint
    CategoryID uint
    Ip         string
    Login      string
    Password   string
}

type JsonEquipment struct {
    ID           *uint
    Category     *string
    Ip           *string
    Login        *string
    Password     *string
}
```

The pointers are there to check if the field is present or not in the JSON. More info: [How to recognize void value and unspecified field when unmarshaling in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365252/how-to-recognize-void-value-and-unspecified-field-when-unmarshaling-in-go)

So for the moment I created a function with many "if" to check and assign to the Equipment but I wonder if there is a better & cleaner solution.

```
func CreateEquipment(item JsonEquipment) (Equipment) {
    e := Equipment{}

    if item.ID != nil && !previousEquipment.Auto { // Is the field present & not automatic equipment
        e.ID = *item.ID
    }

    if item.Ip != nil { // Is the field present ?
        e.Ip = *item.Ip
    }

    if item.Login != nil { // Is the field present ?
        e.Login = *item.Login
    }

    [...]
    return e
}
```

I hope you grasp the idea.

> This question is similar to 
>   [Assign struct with another struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981592/assign-struct-with-another-struct) but is different because of the pointers => non pointers struct

Comment: Why don't you just use interfaces ? And why do you bother checking if the values aren't nil ?

Comment: So let me get the flow straight. 1) You get a equipment as json; 2) You want to check if the equipment's json has all the values you need; 3) Write it to the database using the `Equipment` struct.

Comment: To avoid lots of `if`s you can create simple helper functions for each possible type combo, e.g. `string/*string`, `int/*int`, `int64/*int64`, etc. https://play.golang.org/p/i1c4D6lwY2

Comment: @DenysSéguret If I don't check, I'll get a pointer error; why do I need ? Because when I update an equipment I need to differentiate the case between when I want to set an empty value for example an IP, from the case were I just want to keep the previous value (not assigned)

Comment: @Mihailo Yes, you got the flow!

Comment: @kenfire so would the solution I've provided in the answer bellow work for you?

Comment: @Mihailo actually I don't need ALL the values. The ideal would be to loop over the each elements of the struct to assign them only if it's not nil

Comment: @kenfire I'm not sure I understand you. Your struct must have all of its fields, if they are `nil` they will be present but as the `nil` variation of that particular type. What do you want to achieve/avoid by excluding them?

Comment: @Mihailo In the case of updating an Equipment, if the field is nil, it means that I will not update the field, but if other fields are not nil then they will be updated by the new value.
I might be doing this all wrong, I need a moment to figure out if I really am. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mkopriva Actually it would be more *string => string but I'll test your idea

Comment: @kenfire if you go with *string => string you'll always overwrite what's on `Equipment`. Say you want to update an instance of `Equipment` with only fields that are not `nil` in `JsonEquipment`, keeping the old values on `Equipment`, with *string => string you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a struct with pointer types for your DB data? I.e. get rid of `Equipment` and use `JsonEquipment` for both JSON and DB.

Comment: @Adrian this could be a possibility but as I am using GORM http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html I don"t think I can.

Comment: Why not? Unless GORM has some very strange behavior, I can't think of any reason it couldn't unmarshal a value into a pointer field.

Comment: @Adrian could you give me an example ? In the model definition doc there are no pointers: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#model-definition

Comment: I can't, because I don't use GORM, but just because something isn't in the examples doesn't mean it's not possible. I'd recommend just trying it and seeing if it works.

Comment: I tried but does not work. I'll try to bypass it some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

What I did below works but doesn't do what I intended to.
Actually my first code is the only solution to check the difference between empty field and unspecified field.

Here is the demonstration of the differences:
https://play.golang.org/p/3tU6paM9Do

---

Fist thanks for everyone's help, and particularly to @Mihailo.

What I end up doing is having my models struct without pointers, i.e:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID         uint
    CategoryID uint
    Ip         string
    Login      string
    Password   string
}
```

and I used a JSON helper struct that has a pointer of model struct, i.e

```
type JsonHelper struct {
    Equipments    []*Equipment
    [Add other structures here]
}
```

and finally I parsed the JSON using the JsonHelper struct:

```
func ParseJSON(inputPath string) JsonHelper {
    // Read configuration file
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(inputPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error:", err)
    }

    var input JsonHelper

    // Parse JSON from the configuration file
    err = json.Unmarshal(content, &input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error: ", err)
    }

    return input
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if understood your question correctly but wouldn't something like this do the job:

```
type Equipment struct {
    ID         uint
    CategoryID uint
    Ip         string
    Login      string
    Password   string
}

func main(){
    // Grabing the equipment.
    equips := getEquipment()

    // Checking each equipment for its validity.
    for _, e := range equips {
        if (e.isValid()) {
            fmt.Println(e, "is OK!")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(e, "is NOT OK!")
        }
    }
}

// getEquipment fetches the json from the file.
func getEquipment() (e []Equipment) {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./equipment.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    json.Unmarshal(raw, &e)

    return 
}

// isValid checks if the equipment has all the required fields.
func (e *Equipment) isValid() bool {
    if (e.Ip == "" || e.Login == "") { // You might add more validation rules
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

---

Its pretty straightforward but I'm not sure what more would you want to do here.
This way you have one `Equipment` struct and there's no need of the other "copy" of it containing the pointers.

You can try this code out [here](https://repl.it/@mihailo_misic/Parsing-JSON-example).

Comment: With these verification I will not be able to set "" as an IP, login etc. That's why I need pointers

Comment: This validation is completely optional. I wrote it because I've got the impression that you considered `Equipment` with missing fields as invalid. Do you actually have an existing `Equipment` in the db, and you want to update it with the new one that comes as a json. But during the update you want to change only the fields that have values in the `JsonEquipment` one? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I also do insert and delete depending on the JSON file given