# How to know if yaml integer value is empty

Tags: go, yaml

I'm making a "syntax" validator for .yaml files, I'm trying to know how to validate if integer value from a .yaml file is empty with Go. with strings I don't have any problem, with integer the value default assigned is `0` but it can't help me to determine if is empty.

example yaml:

```
name: "Foo"
age:
```

Go Struct:

```
type Person struct {
     Name string `yaml:"name"`
     Age  int8   `yaml:"age"`
}
```

if age is empty it going to be assigned a `0` by default, if the name is empty you will know due you will have `""`

How could I know if age is empty? I'm using `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` to unmarshal the .yaml.

Comment: By using a pointer type, e.g. `*int8`. See [How to recognize void value and unspecified field when unmarshaling in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365252/how-to-recognize-void-value-and-unspecified-field-when-unmarshaling-in-go/46365300#46365300)

Comment: that worked like charm! 
Thanks @icza

Comment: I'll mark it as duplicate then.